# Can't load ML models in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

I've built a model in Python and saved it with `joblib` from `sklearn.externals` package:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

joblib.dump(rf_Prob_F, 'Model.pkl')
```

When I try to call the model with the following command, an error appears:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib

rf_Prob_F = joblib.load(rf_Prob_F, 'Model.pkl')
```

> NameError: name 'rf_Prob_F' is not defined

What am I missing?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It should be `rf_Prob_F = joblib.load('Model.pkl')`

Answer (score 3):

As written in the [documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/generated/joblib.load.html) 
for `joblib.load()`, you need only the name of the file as an argument:

```
rf_Prob_F = joblib.load('Model.pkl')
```